# Swap values between two rows having a shared value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

I have data in a SQL Server table as below:

```
Name         D/C       Code

Expenses     Debit     10000 
Expenses     Credit    20000
Transport    Debit     50000 
Transport    Credit    60000
```

And I want to swap the code column values like this:

```
Name       D/C       Code

Expenses   Debit     20000
Expenses   Credit    10000
Transport  Debit     60000
Transport  Credit    50000
```

Is there a way to do this using a SQL `UPDATE` command?

Comment: Create a temporary record, insert the values from second row. Update the first row from values of second row. And update the second row from that temporary record. Same for 3rd and 4th.

Answer (score 0):

If you have identity column Try this

```
update t1 
set
t1.code=t2.code
from your_table as t1 inner join your_table as t2
on t1.name=t2.name
where t1.[D/c]='Debit' and t2.[D/c]='Credit' and t1.id_col=t2.id_col-1
```

Comment: Sorry but what is t2? I only have one table here.

Comment: It is the alias for your table. I have used the same table twicw with alias t1 and t2

Comment: Thanks. How about t1.id_col=t2.id_col-1?

Comment: Also, is the ON keyword missing? I think it should be before t1.name=t2.name

Comment: Yes I have modified the code. id_col is the identity column. If you don't have that copy the data in a new temporary table with identity column and run the code

Comment: what does the -1 do on that identity column?

Comment: The -1 instructs that you should take data from previous row where there is Credit for D/C column. Between is the query working correct?